# python check_output prints but doesn't store in var

Tags: python, nginx, subprocess, stderr

I usually use very simply `subprocess.check_output`:

```
process = subprocess.check_output("ps aux", shell=True)
print process #display the list of process
```

If I fear there is something in `stderr`, I use it like that:

```
process = subprocess.check_output("ps aux 2> /dev/null", shell=True)
print process #display the list of process
```

But I have a problem with `nginx -V`:

```
modules = subprocess.check_output("nginx -V", shell=True) #display the result
print modules #empty

modules = subprocess.check_output("nginx -V 2> /dev/null", shell=True) #display nothing
print modules #empty
```

Why is the command `nginx -V` behaving differently (all printing in `stderr`)? How can I design esealy a workaround with ``subprocess.check_output`?

Comment: It might be that a process is specifically printing to the terminal it is run on instead of the normal channels.

Answer (score 0):

The way to redirect standard error to standard output in the shell is `2>&1` but you would do well to avoid using the shell at all here.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['nginx', '-V'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
if out == '':
    modules = err
modules = out
```

If you have a more recent Python, also consider switching to [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess/36008455#36008455 for a general discussion of why to avoid `shell=True`.